# Ext-js data store sharing

Tags: extjs

In the context of Ext-js datastore.
is it a good practice to share data store across multiple components(eg. combobox, grid).
Currently have multiple lists(presented in grids) where I allow user to save their preferences:

```
list1, choose a color
list2, choose a style
...
```

these preferences use a single datastore X.

user can add or remove on each list.

on a separate gui user have these list represented in comboboxes cb1, cb2.
is it a good idea for these comboboxes also use the datastore X and do filter on it?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this question while retagging, so for posterity...

A data store in Ext can easily (and appropriately) be shared among multiple widgets, provided that

- The data (including sort order, filtering, etc.) required by each widget is identical
- You expect data changes originating in one widget to be reflected in all other widgets backed by the same store

In this case, it sounds like the proper approach.